# How to perform incremental load using sqoop tool

Tags: hive, teradata, sqoop

I have my data in Teradata table. I have sqooped that Teradata table data into Hive using sqoop-import command.

But, my Teradata table will get the data on a daily basis. So, there is a need to sqoop the newly added data i.e, incremental data from teradata into Hive table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate, you want to incremente the hive table on daily basis ?

Comment: Do you have some sort of insert/update timestamp in your Teradata table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a any column similar to row-id/timestamp in your table, then you can use:

`--incremental [mode] --last-value [value] --check-column [col]`

If you have a saved job for this, you can skip `--last-value` as it will be automatically maintained.

`--incremental [mode]` has two modes. `lastmodified` and `append`, you can use any one based on your requirement.

Comment: ...and make sure to read very carefully the Sqoop Guide, chapters 12 to 14 https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs >> and ponder that sentence: _"By default, job descriptions are saved to a private repository stored in `$HOME/.sqoop/`"_ (i.e. on the local disk of a specific node) _"You can configure Sqoop to instead use a shared metastore..."_